# print the next positive integer even if the number is an integer itself using math.ceil()

Tags: python

if i am given an integer say `17.81`, i need to convert it to `18`

I tried using `math.ceil()` for this, but the problem is `math.ceil(17.00)` is `17`, and I need the output as `18`

how do I ensure that the `17.00` gets converted to `18` too
my aim is not just to convert the `17.00` to the `18`, but also convert the floats to the next integer

Comment: Since you want functionality other than `ceil`, you need to augment or replace that operation with some code of  your own.  This is a simple value check; where are you stuck?

Comment: You have answers involving `math.floor` and `int`. For positive numbers they both do the same. For negative numbers, there is a difference. If you intend to use this with negative numbers, make sure that you understand this difference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `math.ceil(x)`, you can use `math.floor(x + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `int(x) + 1`.